# Wie nennt man Karton(-stücke), wie sie in Brettspielen zur Anwendung kommen?

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology

Ich frage hier nach einem Fachbegriff, von dem ich *vermute*, dass er existiert - möglicherweise im Bereich Design und Druck, möglicherweise im Bereich der Gesellschaftsspiele, eventuell sogar in beiden.

---

Bei handelsüblichen Brettspielen à la Ravensburger kommt häufig ein relativ stabiler Karton zum Einsatz. Aus diesem besteht normalerweise der Spielplan, je nach Spiel aber auch weitere Spielelemente, z.B. kleinere Plättchen, die sich auf dem Spielplan verteilen lassen oder (z.B. mit Hilfe von Kunststofffüßen aufstellbare) Figuren<sup>1</sup>.

**Nun frage ich mich, wie diese Art Karton heißt - entweder als Material oder spezieller zugeschnitten auf kleinere "Plättchen", falls es dafür einen Ausdruck gibt.**

Hintergrund ist, dass ich ebensolche "Plättchen" gerne entweder bei einer der vielen Online-Druckereien bedrucken lassen oder sie unbedruckt kaufen und dann von Hand beschriften möchte. Zahlreiche Angebote konnte ich finden für blanko Spielkarten und auch Legekarten (das ist offenbar der gängige Begriff für quadratische spielkartenartige Karten, die man nicht auf der Hand hält, sondern in Legespielen verwendet).

Mit "Kartonpapier", "Karton Karten", "Bastelkarton", "Fotokarton" und Ähnlichem landet man stets bei Angeboten mit Papier bis zu einer Stärke von 300 g/m². Wenn ich das mit einem normalen Druckerpapier oder auch hier vorrätigem Bastelkarton vergleiche, ist das zwar durchaus relativ stabil, aber von der Dicke und Festigkeit mit dem Karton, aus dem Brettspielpläne sind, überhaupt nicht zu vergleichen.

Daher gehe ich davon aus, dass ich einfach den korrekten Begriff für das besagte Kartonmaterial (oder Zuschnitte daraus) nicht kenne.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Als Beispiel fällt mir hier auf die Schnelle [*Das verrückte Labyrinth*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_verr%C3%BCckte_Labyrinth) ein, welches nicht nur einen Spielplan enthält, sondern auch quadratische Karten aus dem genannten Kartonmaterial.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke was du suchst ist

> Hartpappe

oder

> Graupappe

Diese ist in verschiedenen Stärken käuflich. Da diese höchstwahrscheinlich nicht durch deinen Drucker laufen werden (Brettspielbögen haben ca. 800g/m²) brauchst du noch entsprechende Aufkleber/Transferfolien.

Spielkarten haben meist eine Stärke von etwa 200-250 g/m².

Kaufen kann man all das online, wie du bereits festgestellt hast. Die Spielbrettbögen sind dann auch schon genutet + verstärkt, z.b. [hier](https://www.spielematerial.de/de/spielmaterial/blankomaterial.html?p=1).

Wie ich gerade sehe hat der Shop auch ein [Wiki](http://www.spieleerfinden.de/wiki/index.php?title=Spielbretter). Für weitere Fragen findest du dort vielleicht schnellere Antworten ^^.

**Anmerkung:**

Wir haben mehrfach Graupappe bestellt. Lass dir diese auf jeden Fall in der Größe zuschneiden wie du sie brauchst, wenn du keine Hebelschneidemaschine hast. Mit ner Schere brauchst du der nicht zu kommen ^^.

Answer (score 1):

> **Nun frage ich mich, wie diese Art Karton heißt - entweder als Material oder spezieller zugeschnitten auf kleinere "Plättchen", falls es dafür einen Ausdruck gibt.**

Der in der Spiele(hersteller) Branche gebräuchliche Fachausdruck für diese Art Kärtchen, Spielpläne (für solche, wo etwas vorgestanzt ist) und Spielfiguren ist offenbar ***Stanztableau*** (oder auch ***Stanzbogen***, s. [mtwde's Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59416/wie-nennt-man-karton-st%c3%bccke-wie-sie-in-brettspielen-zur-anwendung-kommen/59435?noredirect=1#comment145761_59435)).

Ich finde zwar keine Referenz auf DWDS oder Duden Online, dafür aber jede Menge Erwähnungen des Begriffs bei Herstellern von Brettspielen oder Prototypen für Spiele Entwickler.
Hier ein paar exemplarische Links:

- [www.spielematerial.de](https://www.spielematerial.de/de/stanztableaus-seefahrer.html)
- [www.assaltenburger.de](https://www.assaltenburger.de/de/spieleproduktion/portfolio/spielplaene-tableaus/)
- [www.spiele-offensive.de](https://www.spiele-offensive.de/Kundentestbericht/Spielbox-4-2015-inkl-Stanztableau-fuer-Puzzle-Strike-1016899.html)
- [www.infigo.gmbh](https://www.infigo.gmbh/spiele-drucken-spiele-erstellen-brettspiele/)
- [www.kinderspielmagazin.de](https://www.kinderspielmagazin.de/2020/02/02/neue-spielemanufaktur-fuer-brettspiele-aus-dem-premiumsegment/)
- ...

Comment: Ein anderes Wort dafür ist Stanzbogen. Allerdings ist das Stanztableau, soweit ich weiß, das komplette Ding aus dem man die (vorgestanzten Papp-) Figuren, Plättchen, etc herauslösen muss, nicht das einzelne Element. Das Stanztableau umfasst also auch den Rahmen den man wegwirft. Da der Spielplan idR nicht ausgelöst wird ist er auch kein Stanztableau.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis, ich werde es in die Antwort mit aufnehmen. _"Da der Spielplan idR nicht ausgelöst wird ist er auch kein Stanztableau."_ Das kommt darauf an. Wenn ich mich recht erinnere mussten wir z.B. beim Spiel ["Der zerstreute Pharao"](https://www.amazon.de/Ravensburger-26426-Der-zerstreute-Pharao/dp/B000MVVCZO) auch die vorgestanzten Löcher aus dem Spielplan herauslösen. Aber Du hast ja geschrieben _idR_.

Answer (score 0):

Mehr als **Kärtchen aus Pappe** oder zusammengezogen **Pappkärtchen** fällt mir nicht dazu ein. Dieser Begriff wird offenbar auch breiter verwendet, z. B. im Wikipedia-Artikel für [Cartino](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartino), das solche Teile nach dem Photo zu schließen verwendet.

**Kartonstärke** könnte der Begriff sein, der Druckereien weiterhilft.